How to build to Android from Windows with the right C++ standard version?
I am trying to build from Windows to Android with Android NDK and MinGWg-w64 (winlibs-x86_64-posix-seh-gcc-14.2.0-llvm-18.1.8-mingw-w64ucrt-12.0.0-r1)
Everything goes fine until I got an error like this:
D:\Projects\ProjectFoo\src\someFile.cpp:29:11: error: no member named 'push_range' in 'std::stack<TIntermNode *>'
    stack.push_range(analyzer.getPipelineOutputs());
    ~~~~~ ^
:\Projects\ProjectFoo\src\someFile.cpp:90:23: error: no member named 'push_range' in 'std::stack<TIntermNode *>'
                stack.push_range(Nodes);
                ~~~~~ ^

I guess this is because the push_range function is only after the C++ 23 standard. I included this into my CMakeLists.txt as well as in my build script, but it seem it has been ignored. Or is there a problem with the compiler?
This is my build script:
@echo off

    call :build arm64-v8a
    if errorlevel 1 goto error
    
    exit /b 0
    
    :build
    set ANDR_ARCH=%~1
    
    set ANDR_NDK_HOME=D:\Android\ndk\26.1.10909125
    set MINGW_MAKE_PATH=D:\winlibs-x86_64-posix-seh-gcc-14.2.0-llvm-18.1.8-mingw-w64ucrt-12.0.0-r1\mingw64\bin
    
    rd /s /q %ANDR_ARCH% > nul 2>&1
    
    mkdir %ANDR_ARCH%
    cd %ANDR_ARCH%
    C:\CMake\bin\cmake.exe -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..^
        -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="%MINGW_MAKE_PATH%\mingw32-make.exe"^
        -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="%ANDR_NDK_HOME%\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake"^
        -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release^
        -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android^
        -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a^
        -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=26^
    pause
    
    if errorlevel 1 exit /b errorlevel
    C:\CMake\bin\cmake.exe --build . -j 12
    pause
    cd ..
    exit /b 0
    
    :error
    cd ..
    pause
    exit /b errorlevel


OT: There is no need to call cmake every time. cmake --build will notice when it needs to regenerate the build system.

MinGW is unrelated to Android, it compiles for Windows.

This has nothing to do with your MinGW compiler but your NDK version.
Android NDK 26.1 comes with a certain version of Clang and Libc++ from January 2023. Meanwhile, the commit that added std::stack::push_range was merged in June 2023.
Update your NDK to r27 or later and that specific method will be part of libc++.
EDIT: you can verify this yourself by locating the libc++ header files inside the NDK
